# Thumbnails for media Library images

Tags: plugin-development, post-thumbnails, media, media-library, thumbnails

I have somee Item in the media library, where I want to retrieve the thunbnail from.
I use the normal post thumbnail functions (tried some of them), with normal posts or cpts's the work fine.

As media library items are handled, similiar to posts, I thought the normal wp thumb function could work there, too. There are also thumbs created, as i can see on the server.

But no one fo WP's Thumb Fuunctions returns that thumb.

Here an example Function, I use:

```
 <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'size-1'); ?>
```

The post ID is correct. The Thumbnail size is registered and works for other posts fine.

Thank YOu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID, 'size-1');`

The "post thumbnail" actually gets the featured image that is attached to the post. For an attachment, you want the attachment itself in a specific size, which isn't the same as the featured image.